Why doesn't it recognize any selections on the datepicker?
I'm trying to populate a select dropdown with the hours that don't have appointments booked, and right now I'm experiencing somethin really dumb with datepicker, because I want it to be populated based on the selected doctor in the selected day, but it seems to not even recognize that a day has been selected When I do select it.
This is my AJAX call
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            onSelect: function() {
                setTimeout(triggerAjaxCall, 0);
            }
        });

        $('#selMedico').change(function(){
            triggerAjaxCall();
        });

        function triggerAjaxCall() {
            var doctor = $('#selMedico').val();
            var date = $('#datepicker').val();

            console.log('Doctor:', doctor);
            console.log('Date:', date); 

            if (!doctor || !date) {
                console.log('Doctor or date not selected');
                return;
            }

            // AJAX call
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'fetchConsultas.php',
                data: { medico: doctor, dia: date },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log('AJAX request successful');
                    console.log('Response:', response);  

                    $('#hora').empty();
                    $.each(response, function(index, value) {
                        $('#hora').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('AJAX request failed:', textStatus, errorThrown);  
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>

and this is my fetchConsultas.php file
<?php
if (isset($_POST['medico']) && isset($_POST['dia'])) {

    $medicoSelecionado = $_POST['medico'];
    $dataSelecionada = $_POST['dia'];

    include 'connection.php';

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id_hora 
                            FROM tabconsultas 
                            WHERE id_medico = ? 
                            AND id_dia = ? ;');
    
    $stmt->execute([$medicoSelecionado, $dataSelecionada]);

    $horarios = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

    // Create an array of all the hours from 08:00:00 to 18:00:00 (excluding 13:00:00)
    $allHours = [];
    for ($i = 8; $i <= 18; $i++) {
        if ($i != 13) {
            $hour = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':00:00';
            $allHours[] = $hour;
        }
    }

    // Get the hours that are not in the result of the query
    $availableHours = array_diff($allHours, $horarios);

    echo json_encode($availableHours);

    $pdo = null;
    $stmt = null;
} else {
    echo "No doctor or date selected.";
}
die();

I'm pretty sure that there's something wrong with the datepicker plugin itself, but I'm not very experienced, so I'm hoping someone can help me find out a way to go over this.
Note: It actually populates the dropdown correctly If I :

select a doctor and then select a date, then select another random doctor and finally go back to the doctor selected at first.

Just like what's happening here:

As you can see, it goes from doctor 2 with no date, to doctor 6 with a date, because it only triggers when I select a doctor, and it should be triggering when I select a doctor AND a date!
As asked in the post, I'm addin the HTML code for doctor selection and date.
 $consulta = "SELECT DISTINCT tabutilizador.id_utilizador, tabutilizador.nome  
                    FROM tabutilizador
                    LEFT JOIN tabconsultas ON tabutilizador.id_utilizador = tabconsultas.id_medico 
                    WHERE tabutilizador.tipo = 'medico'";

        $resultado = $conexao->query($consulta);
        //Lista de médicos
        echo '<form id="formulario" action="formhandler.inc.php" method="POST">';
        echo '<label for="medico">Médico</label><br><br>';
        echo '<select id="selMedico" name="medico" onchange="fetchServicosPorMedico(this.value)" required>';
        echo '<option value="" disabled select selected>Escolha um Médico</option>';
        while ($linha = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<option value="' . $linha['id_utilizador'] . '">' . $linha['nome'] . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select><br><br>';

and as for the date:
echo '<label for="dia">Data da Consulta</label><br><br>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="dia" placeholder="Selecione uma data" required><br><br>';

I'm also adding the overall scheme of the database, as it was also asked:

I've been thinking, and as I've destroyed and generated a new datepicker before, in order to populate it correctly enabling only the days the selected doctor works on, I guess something around here might be causing this to happen?
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#selMedico').change(function() {
            var medicoSelecionado = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'fetchDiasPorMedico.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    medico: medicoSelecionado
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#resultado').html(response);
                    var diasDisp = response;
                    $(function() {
                        $("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy").datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                            dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda-feira', 'Terça-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sábado'],
                            dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb'],
                            dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb'],
                            monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
                            monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
                            nextText: 'Próximo',
                            prevText: 'Anterior',
                            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                var day = date.getDay();
                                // Avalia a lógica em qualquer para determinar se o dia deve ser desabilitado
                                var disableDay = new Function('day', 'return ' + diasDisp);
                                return [disableDay(day), ''];
                            },
                            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                                var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                                var dayOfWeek = selectedDate.getDay();
                            },
                            minDate: 0
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });


Can you update your question by adding the html code snippet of the doctor and date selection ?

Is this a JS problem, an AJAX problem, or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Just woke up. I'm going to edit the post and add the HTML for the dare selection and doctor selection.

I'm not sure of what's making it not recognize the selection. As I said I'm pretty new to this so I searched and found onSelect function which I've tried and still didnt work, and also tried trigerring datepicker manually, which also didnt work.

FYI: isset() can receive multiple parameters.  for attributes only relate to id attributes, not name attributes.  It is never necessary to declare the value attribute of a select option if it is identical to the option text.

I created this codesnippet only to make sure that doctor and date both can be selected perfectly.
Check the codesnippet here (Hope this can help you):


$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      onSelect: function() {
                setTimeout(triggerAjaxCall, 0);
            }
    });
     $('#selMedico').change(function() {
            var medicoSelecionado = $(this).val();
                    var diasDisp = [true, true, false, true, false, true]; //The response returned from server will appear here

// remove $(function() { }) 
// do not initiate datepicker here within $(function()) as this will work only on load not work dynamically. 
//So simply implement within the server response block

$("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy").datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                            dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda-feira', 'Terça-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sábado'],
                            dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb'],
                            dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb'],
                            monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
                            monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
                            nextText: 'Próximo',
                            prevText: 'Anterior',
                            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                var day = date.getDay();
                                // Avalia a lógica em qualquer para determinar se o dia deve ser desabilitado
                                var disableDay = new Function('day', 'return ' + diasDisp[day]);
                                return [disableDay(day), ''];
                            },
                            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                                var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                                var dayOfWeek = selectedDate.getDay();
                                setTimeout(triggerAjaxCall, 0); // Call triggerAjaxCall here, You forgot to call here
                            },
                            minDate: 0
                            
                        });
                    });
                
            
    
  } );
function triggerAjaxCall() {
            var doctor = $('#selMedico').val();
            var date = $('#datepicker').val();
                         
            if (!doctor || !date) {
                alert('Doctor or date not selected');
                return;
            }
            else
            {
              alert("Doctor: " + doctor+"   Date: "+date);
            }
  /*
  Here comes the AJAX POST request code 
  */
}
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="doctorselection">
      <form id="docselform">
        <label>Select Doctor: </label>
        <select id="selMedico"> 
          <option value="" selected> Select a Doctor</option>
          <option value="DR. ABC"> Dr. ABC</option>
          <option value="DR. XYZ"> Dr. XYZ</option>
          <option value="DR. PQR"> Dr. PQR</option>
        </select>
       <br />
       <label>Select Date: </label>     
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" />    
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



EDIT
In your edited question you mentioned

"I've been thinking, and as I've destroyed and generated a new
datepicker before..."

You are right . on $(document).ready(function() {}) the datepicker was inititalized which was triggering the function triggerAjaxCall on date selection , but when its destroying and reinitiating datepicker then you forgot to add triggerAjaxCall.

As you can see, it goes from doctor 2 with no date, to doctor 6 with a
date, because it only triggers when I select a doctor, and it should
be triggering when I select a doctor AND a date!

This is because you called triggerAjaxCall within $('#selMedico').change(function(){ ...}), call it in Datepicker Option onSelect
In your code you have implemented datePicker destroy and reintializaiton within $(function(){....}) which is being called within $('#selMedico').change(function() { ... }) .
$(document).ready(function() {}) and $(function(){....}) are same both of them triggered when DOM is ready. But within onChange function you need not to call onReady , write the code of datePicker destroy outside $(function(){....})
Now recheck the code snippet, I tried to create the scenario with static data (no ajax, no php). Check, compare with your code and replace as necessary

Yes, your snippet works perfectly fine, but if I jus ttry this code in my project it still doesn't work. Could it be because of the manipulation I've had to do before onto datepicker in order to filter dates by schedules?

I've made the changes you asked for the post, I don't know if there's a way for me to share the database with you from here, if there is, please let me know and I'll do it.

@JoséFilipeSilva
After reviewing your update in question I have updated the answer and code snippet for your relevance and I think the problem is in your way of calling or initiiating datePicker function . Check and run the code snippet above again. Do the needful changes in your code .
